# Large-scale jQuery selector caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

What patterns are available for caching many jQuery selectors in a large-scale JavaScript application for repeated reuse?

There has been much said about storing jQuery selectors in simple variables inside simple functions, but within a JavaScript object, for example in the popular module pattern, how can one cleanly setup and store them?

My initial attempt was to use global variables, but that dirties the namespace and could cause conflicts. My second attempt involved storing the selectors within an object literal inside a corresponding object, but that leads to longer-than-desired calls on them, for example:

```
var Module = {

  nodes: {},

  storeSelectorsInCache: function() {
    Module.nodes = {
      form: $('#form'),
      grid: $('#grid')
    };
  },

  initialize: function() {
    Module.storeSelectorsInCache();

    // notice the long hierarchy to get to Module.nodes.form
    Module.nodes.form.submit(function() {
      // event handler
    });
  }

};
```

There must be a cleaner shorthand out there somewhere.

Comment: You could assign `Module.nodes` to a variable with a short name and use that variable afterwards.

Comment: Or you could work within an IIFE then just use plain variables, thus avoiding polluting the global namespace while allowing you to use shorter easier names for your variables.

Comment: What's wrong with simple (module-)local variables?

Comment: The real question is why you need to cache your selectors. have you identified them as being the choke point of your application? I find that when most selections are done in an asynchronous manner (as part of an animation, ajax callback, event, etc), the cost of selection tends to be negligible.

Comment: I have about thirty selectors that are reused often in an intensive app. I measure significant performance improvements with caching.

Comment: Kevin, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might be cool:

```
var _nodes = {};

var Module = {
  /**
   * You could call this when you want to query a selector and store it for reuse. Then 
   * just use this for querying.
   * 
   * @param {String} selector The selector to memoize.
   * @param forceUpdate {Boolean} jQuery selectors don't update with their DOM 
   *     counterparts. This will take that into account. Pass in true to override cache.
   *
   * @return {Object<Array<jQuery>>} The matching selectors.
   */
  $: function(selector, forceUpdate) {
    if (forceUpdate === true || !({}).hasOwnProperty.call(_nodes, selector)) {
      _nodes[selector] = jQuery(selector); // Not that robust, just a basic example
    }
    return _nodes[selector];
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.$('#form').submit(function () { /* ... */ });
  }
};
```

So with this every time you query for a selector using the locally-scoped `Module.$` function it would cache the result in the nodes object (which here is being exploited as an associative array). However if there was no result for that selector in the nodes object then it would query the DOM for it. Furthermore there's an added param to force the selectors in `nodes` to be updated.

Alternatively you could use lodash's [memoize](http://lodash.com/docs#memoize) function, like so:

```
// inside your Module
$: _.memoize(jQuery);
```